# Django-import-export - import of advanced fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, satchmo, django-import-export

For a Django model I'm using [django-import-export](https://github.com/bmihelac/django-import-export) package.

If need to export more then just available model fields, like properties or custom fields, new can be added with `import_export.fields.Field` class and optionally `dehydrate_<field>` method.

```
from import_export import resources, fields, instance_loaders

class ProductResource(resources.ModelResource):
    categories  = fields.Field()
    price       = fields.Field(attribute='unit_price')

    class Meta:
        model  = Product

    def dehydrate_categories(self, product):
        return ';'.join(
                '/%s' % '/'.join([c.name for c in cat.parents()] + [cat.name])
                for cat in product.category.iterator() )
```

It does work well, but only for exporting. What about import, the reverse process ? Is there some counterpart to `dehydrate_` method ?

So far I've overridden `get_or_init_instance` method:

```
class ProductResource(resources.ModelResource):
    def get_or_init_instance(self, instance_loader, row):
        row['unit_price'] = row['price']; row.pop('price')
        return super(ProductResource, self).get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
```

but doubt this is the right way.

Would appreciate any hint how to handle imports of custom fields.

Answer (score 5):

You can override `import_obj` instead. See [Import workflow](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/import_workflow.html) for more details.

Another approach is to subclass [Field](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api_fields.html) and override `export` and `save` methods and do all required data manipulation in a field.

Comment: Thanks. Sure, overriding Field methods is a good idea but I've been just interested if there is already some way how to import custom field contents previously exported with `dehydrate_` methods. Don't like to reinvent a wheel ..

Comment: I asked similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655339/django-admin-import-export-module-used-for-custom-import Maybe you can help with your experience with django-import-export?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old but I came across the same problem and this is how I fixed it (based on the direction the original asker was heading).
First, you can add any custom/modified fields you need by overriding the 'before_import_row' function, like so:

```py
    def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
        row['extra_info'] = 'Some Info'
        return super(RetailLocationResource, self).before_import_row(row, **kwargs)
```

Then you can pass this into your instance by overriding get_or_init_instance like so:

```py
    def get_or_init_instance(self, instance_loader, row):
        instance, bool = super(RetailLocationResource, self).get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
        instance.extra_info = row['extra_info']
        return instance, bool
```

Hope this helps anyone!